# Did Judas play an important role for God’s salvation?

Tags: life-of-jesus, soteriology, crucifixion, judas-iscariot

In reading the bible, we see Judas as the great enemy who betrayed our Lord Jesus. But looking in a different perspective, was his role gave benefit for the fulfilment of death and crucifixion of the Saviour Christ. Without Judas, would there still be a death and crucifixion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Acts 2 Peter addresses a Jewish crowd and says that the death of Jesus was both the act of humans and the plan of God:

> Acts 2:22-23 NIV: Fellow Israelites, listen to this: Jesus of Nazareth was a man accredited by God to you by miracles, wonders and signs, which God did among you through him, as you yourselves know. This man was handed over to you by God’s deliberate plan and foreknowledge; and you, with the help of wicked men, put him to death by nailing him to the cross.

This reflects the traditional [compatibilist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibilism) view that two things are simultaneously true: that God's will is completely sovereign, while humans have real wills.

If Judas had not desired to betray Jesus we can conclude that Jesus's death would have gone ahead according to God's plan. Indeed, even within the Gospels it's not really clear that Judas accomplished much; the Jewish leaders knew who Jesus was and he wasn't trying to hide from them. Perhaps all that Judas accomplished was alerting them to where Jesus was at a time when they could arrest him without the whole city observing, so that he could be killed in time for Passover.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just get confuse about free will and predestination. To tell you the truth, I do feel sorry for Judas, because if he truely knew what he was doing, he will not betray our Lord.

Comment: @KayleeA That's true for all of us, and yet we still sin.

Comment: Yes, I do not want to be put in that position and no one does. For me it is a struggle to pass this trial while I’m on this flesh. While we live in this world, it is a matter of survival. Self interest and greed always kicks in.

Comment: @KayleeA Do not feel sorry, because Judas only betrayed their "friendship",Jesus is the one who commanded Judas to accomplish his desire for money, as Jesus said, "go, do it quickly". If you were Jesus and you know Judas will end up in hell, would you still allow Judas to go? It would be better, if Jesus said, "please stay here, do not betray our friendship". That's why Jesus still called Judas His "friend" after his kiss. And Jesus lay down His life for his friends. The true candidate for "betrayer" was Peter & the rest of Apostles because they professed their "oath", while Judas did not.

Comment: @KayleeA If we read the gospel, although Judas sold Jesus for thirty pieces, it coudl have been prevented if Jesus say to Judas, please do not push thru with your betrayal because I could not save you if you do that. But instead, Jesus is the one who even commanded Judas, to go quickly and accomplished his betrayal Have you thought about this?

Comment: Yes, you have a good point. We have our own freewill and you pay for the consequences. It is only through Jesus mercy and forgiveness and His death on the cross that could bring us to salvation.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus set the example for his disciples. He knew intimately who he chose and each one learned from Him so this raises a point: Judas did what he had to do.

As an example, consider Jeremiah. God knew Jeremiah before he was conceived, and He created Jeremiah for a specific purpose. From Jeremiah 1:

> 4 The word of the Lord came to me, saying,
> 5 “Before I formed you in the womb I knew you,
> before you were born I set you apart;
> I appointed you as a prophet to the nations.”

From this I understand that God created Judas to do what he did as an act of love, for us. Jesus knew of this from the beginning, and His love for him was special. Judas suffered more than any of the other disciples for what he did and Jesus could not tell the others, save one, about Judas or what he had to do. The one Jesus told, wrote about it.

I can't conceive worshiping a God that would create a life to be used for condemnation and hated, and then cast it aside. This is not what Jesus taught. Jesus sent Judas to do what he had to do (John 13:27) and he did it. Judas was an instrument of God that was used to give God's children a way back to Him.

I see great love in the the events that led to the crucifixion of Jesus Christ. There is great love shown through John 21, and John, through the guidance of God's Spirit, captured it perfectly.

I know what I've shared is not what is taught about Judas, but this is what my studies and prayers have shown me.

Jesus has Risen!

Answer (score -1):

*Did Judas play an important role for God’s salvation?*

**The answer is a big YES!**

Although Judas was tempted to sell Jesus for thirty pieces of silver, Jesus could have prevented Judas betrayal easily, how?

Let's compare Peter and Judas and the action of Jesus Christ, when He knew that Satan was the one behind them.

When Peter, spoke the things that Satan wanted to say, Jesus immediately rebuked him, and said, **"Get behind me Satan"**...

> But Jesus turned and said to Peter, “Get behind Me, Satan! You are a stumbling block to Me. For you do not have in mind the things of God, but the things of men.” -Matthew16:23

While in the case of Judas, it was clear in the scripture, that Judas was in the "state of sin", it was a mortal sin. But, the question is, why would Jesus gave Judas the consecrated bread dipped in wine, as Catholic Church teaches, the consecrated bread and wine, is the body,blood,soul and divinity of Christ himself, and must be receive reverently. And so, when Judas received the holy eucharist from the hands of Jesus Christ, it was an entry point for Satan.

Have you wonder why Jesus, in the case of Peter, He immediately rebuked Satan, but in the case of Judas, when Jesus saw Satan enters the soul of Judas, He did not rebuke it, but instead, commanded Judas to go on with his betrayal?

> And when Judas had taken the morsel, Satan entered into him. Then Jesus said to Judas, “What you are about to do, do quickly.” -John13:27

Instead of rebuking Satan, Jesus let go of Judas, and also, He was the one who commanded Judas to fulfill his betrayal, why?

Because, Jesus has a saving plan for Judas, as He knew that He can save Judas even in hell, as He will descend into hell to free souls who are in prison, including Judas.

The simple question is, if you were Judas, and you saw Jesus preaching the gospel of salvation in hell, offering the infinite mercy of God, will you come to Jesus and say...forgive me my Lord, I had betrayed you and not look upon you as the "Son of Man", but now, I believe that you are truly the Messiah, Son of the Living God.

Will Jesus say to Judas in hell, seeking His mercy, will Jesus say, away from me, I do not know you! Remember, Judas is a friend of Jesus, and Jesus laid down His life for His friends, but His friends are the one who followed His commands.

And Judas followed, Jesus commands to go quickly and betray Him..

> Greater love has no one than this, that he lay down his life for his friends. 14**You are My friends if you do what I command you.** -John15:13-14

Judas was a friend of Jesus, and Judas followed Jesus commands. That's why Ab.Paglia said, **"For a Catholic, to say Judas is in hell, is heresy"**

Judas is not in hell, but most probably is now in Heaven.

And Judas, preach the evil of suicide better than all the Apostles and disciples combined.

[Archbishop Paglia Says It’s Heresy to Say Judas Is in Hell](https://catholicism.org/archbishop-paglia-says-its-heresy-to-say-judas-is-in-hell.html)

Comment: **”For a Catholic, to say Judas is in hell, is heresy"** That is so not true: “Faithful Catholics are criticizing his comment, recalling how Our Lord spoke of Judas: "The Son of Man indeed goes, as it is written of him: but woe to that man by whom the Son of Man shall be betrayed. It were better for him, if that man had not been born." The Saints, Fathers and Doctors of the Church say unanimously that Judas is in Hell.” - [Abp. Vincenzo Paglia contradicts the tradition of the Church](https://www.churchmilitant.com/news/article/vatican-official-claims-its-heresy-to-say-judas-in-hell)

Comment: @KenGraham Judas never look upon Jesus as the "Son of Man", so how can Judas betrayed Jesus as the "Son of Man"? Remember it is very clear in scriptures, and repeated by all the gospel writers, Judas only look upon Jesus as "Rabbi
nothing more nothing less.  And one more thing, Judas went into hell, but Jesus descended into hell too to preach the gospel of salvation, do you think Jesus wont look upon Judas, his friend, whom he gave the bread dipped in wine and the one He commanded to fulfill his betrayal quickly. Judas is in Heaven not hell. Be wise Ken. -Ave!